# PostGIS change column type varchar => geometry

Tags: postgis, geometry

I have a Postgres database with PostGIS extension on it. Also, I have a table with column lat with type `(varchar 40)`. Column values are like this:

```
52.1432514
52.1431855
52.1431586
```

I want to convert the whole column to `geometry` type. When I do `ALTER TABLE m_copy ALTER COLUMN latitude TYPE geometry USING (latitude::geometry);` I see an error:

```
ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry
SQL state: XX000
Hint: "52.1432514" <-- parse error at position 11 within geometry
```

What am I doing wrong and what is the right query?

P.S Also I have a lon column. Maybe it is better to combine that columns?

Comment: The latitude value alone doesn't define a point, and needs to be combined with longitude for sure. You should create a new geometry column; I think the syntax you need is either [ST_MakePoint](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_MakePoint.html) or [ST_PointFromText](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_PointFromText.html)?

Answer (score 3):

You probably should just create a new column and I would suggest if you are new to PostGIS, you probably want to use geography instead of geometry. So somethng like

```
ALTER TABLE m_copy ADD COLUMN geog geography(POINT,4326);
UPDATE m_copy SET geog = ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(longitude,latitude),4326)::geography;
```

If you decide to use geometry, just replace the geography (and geog) with geometry and geom